# Bitbake "no reply from server in 30s" after running a few tasks

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to run Yocto Linux builds under a WSL2 environment.

I successfully built an image for my embedded system with `bitbake imx-image-full`. Then I wanted to create the SDK via `bitbake -c populate_sdk imx-image-full`. It starts normally, but after a few minutes of running tasks, bitbake "hangs": several `do_compile` tasks are in progress, timers are running, but nothing actually finishes. The system became idle: `htop` shows that all CPUs are at 0%, and the fans aren't spinning any faster.

Hitting Ctrl-C causes the following message to appear:

> No reply from server in 30s

I restarted the whole system and cleared the caches, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a closer look at `htop` and noticed that all the CPUs go 100%, then the memory usage, first the RAM, then the swap. Then the CPU usage drops to 0 just after the swap bar completely filled up. I suspect that all processes die due to lack of enough memory.

I [increased the available RAM for WSL](https://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2022/01/setting-your-memory-and-swap-for-wsl2.html) from 16GB to 24GB (my system has 32GB physical RAM), and increased the swap to 48G just to have plenty of buffer.

The build is currently running, with a peak of 21-22GB usage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should reduce the number of parralel yocto build with:

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "your_custom_number"
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j your_custom_number"
```

To avoid restarting system after this message:

```
No reply from server in 30s
```

You should delete in your build directory (which contain tmp and conf directory) a file named bitbake.lock

Comment: Makes sense, likely it stopped when all my 12 cores tried to use more than 1.5GB of RAM each.